# send one form and print the same form in another php

Tags: php, html, forms

How to make this same form by clicking the submit button, you send the same form to another php by POST method form where the inputs type text appear filled and the select will be select with the same  option selected that the first form. I hope understand my explanation.

HTML

```
<form id="formPOST" action="pr01post.php" method="POST" >
        Nombre<input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre"/><br>
        Edad<input type="text" id="txtEdad" name="txtEdad"/><br>
        Provincia<select id="selProv" name="selProv">
                    <option value='0'>Seleccione una provincia</option>
                    <option value='1'>Álava</option>
                    <option value='2'>Albacete</option>
                    <option value='3'>Alicante/Alacant</option> 
                 </select><br>
        Fec. Nac.:<input type="text" id="txtFecNac" name="txtFecNac"/><br>
        Sexo: Hombre<input type="radio" name="radSex" value="Varón" checked>Mujer<input type="radio" name="radSex" value="Mujer">
        <input type="submit" name="subEnv" />          
    </form>
```

Comment: is it posible do it without to use jquery?

Comment: You use PHP to pre-fill in the form based on the inputs, then spit out the same form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of jQuery, Luke!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selProv option[value="<?=$_POST['selProv'];?>"]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
</script>
```

And be sure you've included actual jquery lib on your page. Can do it like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
```